# What is "0" mean in a 2D char array (char* []) in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I recently encounter a C interview coding question. A general function like "void Foo(char** sarr)". And it gives me a input

```
char* data[] = {"4352", "3242", "2432143", "234", "", "324", 0}
```

I am kind of new to C, but familiar with C++. For this case, I really don't know what does this '0' mean in this char* array. I know C has a terminator for string as '\0'. But what 0 means? Or this input is simply wrong/invalid?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's an empty string (equivalent to `""`) **EDIT: I'm wrong. It isn't.**

Comment: @Aziz No it isn't.

Comment: It is a sentinel: value `NULL`, to indicate the end of the array.

Comment: You should not get any error here. This should work just fine.

Comment: To those all said it should be fine with my compiler. YES u r right I was wrong :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0` is one of the ways to write a null pointer constant in C. It would probably be more obvious if they'd written:

```
char* data[] = {"4352", "3242", "2432143", "234", "", "324", NULL};
```

which is equivalent.

The null pointer is being used as an indicator of the end of the array (similar to the way the character `'\0'` marks the end of strings. If you're iterating over the array, you can use something like:

```
for (var i = 0; data[i] != 0; i++) {
    // do something with data[i]
}
```

You can also use `data[i] != NULL;`, they're equivalent.

Comment: So how should I detect it has terminated in the function? Would it be if(data[iterator] == 0) or (*iterator == 0) ?

Comment: @milanow Yes, that's how you'd do it, unless you decided to use Barmar's version. In that case, you'd want to do `if (data[iterator] == NULL)` or `if (*data == NULL)`.

Comment: `data[iterator] == 0`, `data[iterator] == NULL`, and `!data[iterator]` all do the same thing: Check whether `data[iterator]` is a null pointer.

Comment: @melpomene True, but it seems like the OP is simply trying to find the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ NULL is effectively the same thing to numerical 0. It is ok to have NULL pointer as an element of an array of pointers. Your `char *data[]` is an array of pointers.

This causes problems because in many cases it would be nice to distinguish integer 0 from NULL pointer. That is why since C++ 11 `nullptr` and `nullptr_t` were introduced. I would definitely recommend using them instead of NULL or 0.

Comment: The question is for C, so C++ specific constructs like `nullptr` don't apply here.

Answer (score 2):

You declared an array of pointers, and the last element of the array is set to zero, which is effectively a `NULL` pointer. In fact, the `NULL` macro is usually defined as `(void *) 0`, although its value is implementation dependent.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I guess it is usually defined that way, am I right? If yes we can fix it that way.

Answer (score -1):

NULL is a pointer defined usually as (void*) 0. This is used to declare the pointer which is pointing to nothing, it's usually used to show the end of list/tree, or that pointer was not allocated etc.

Comment: Anyone can say to me what's wrong in my answer that I'm getting down-votes?

Comment: `NULL` isn't necessarily a pointer. `#define NULL 0` is allowed by the standard.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks!